# Making a field readonly in Catalog -> Manage Product -> General tab?

Tags: magento

I have added a new field named `category` with a text box in Catalog -> Manage Product -> General tab, via the Manage Attributes and Attribute Sets tab. I want to make this field readonly. Please help me anyone. How can I do this, and tell me the page source.

Thanks

Comment: But then how would you set it in the first place?

Comment: Dude, I told you on your question that you asked earlier today.  Accept previous answers or you won't get a response.  Seriously.

Comment: Also, you need to show us that you have tried to work this out for yourself.  What files have you tried editing?

Comment: hi...Jonathan Day i solved that problem..by changing app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml file like <?php $_element = $this->getElement() ?>
<?php $this->checkFieldDisable() ?>
<?php
// START: My Change
if((strpos(trim($this->getElementHtml()), '"categories"') !== false)){
    $_element->setDisabled(true);
} 
// END: My Change
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved that problem..by changing

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/form/renderer/fieldset/ele­ment.phtml 
file like

$_element = $this->getElement() ?> checkFieldDisable()

// START: My Change
if((strpos(trim($this->getElementHtml()), '"categories"') !== false))

{

$_element->setDisabled(true);

} 
// END: My Change ?>